# I bought a premium domain and now the registrar says that domain wasn't really available for purchase

Tags: public-domain, domain-name

I purchased a domain name from a popular domain registrar, I immediately got the confirmation email and receipt for the purchased domain but the domain wasn't added to my account so I contacted the GoDaddy support, they said as I won the domain in auction so it may take up to 7 days to transfer the domain to may account. I waited for 7 days and contacted the GoDaddy support again, they said please wait for some more time and If problem still persists after 14 days you can email at auctions@godaddy.com to resolve the issue. As my issue wasn't solved even after 14 days, I contacted the support via that email address and I got the following response.

> Unfortunately, due to an unexpected issue this domain was recently made available for purchase in error. This domain should not have been available for registration, auction, or capture via backorder.
>
> We have refunded your full purchase amount and we are taking proactive steps to prevent this error from happening again in the future.
>
> Please accept our sincere apologies for any confusion this issue may have caused.
>
> Thank you for your understanding and for choosing Go Daddy.

I was assured that I got that domain and did some commitments with that domain. is there any legal action can be taken against registrar for such kind of act?

Comment: If you actually suffered damages, maybe. Any answer would involve speaking to a lawyer though.

Answer (score 7):

### No

You agreed to this:

> If the change of ownership from Seller to Buyer is not able to be completed (i) due to either party’s fraudulent activity or (ii) for any other reason, Buyer and Seller acknowledge and agree that GoDaddy shall have no liability or responsibility regarding the same.

You got your refund - that’s all they owe you.